# Add output to the "FAILURES" section of a test, while not capturing stdout

Tags: python, pytest

I have a custom decorator on my tests that just gives some extra info to the test. I'd like that when a test fails, I can print some of this info and have it show up in the failures section, so our build tools can display it well.

Right now I just have some code that looks like this:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    if outcome.get_result().outcome != "passed":
        print("Some extra info: {}".format(item.function.detail1))
```

The problem is that this when a test fails I get output that looks like this:

```
test_foo.py .Some extra info: more info
F

================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_foo2 __________________________________

    @info("more info")
    def test_foo():
>       raise ValueError("OH NO")
E       ValueError: OH NO

test_foo.py:11: ValueError
```

I'd like the `Some extra info: more info` to showup in that bottom section. Is it possible to hook into this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick working solution although I'm sure there is probably more py(test)thonic way to do this.

**test.py**

```
def test_fail():
    assert False

def test_pass():
    assert True

def test_fail_2():
    assert False
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

FAIL_EXTRA_INFO = []

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    if outcome.get_result().outcome != "passed":
        FAIL_EXTRA_INFO.append("Some extra info: {}".format(item))

def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus):
    for extra_info in FAIL_EXTRA_INFO:
        print(extra_info)
```

**Execution result:**

```
$ pytest -v
======================== test session starts =======================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.0, pytest-3.6.2, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0 
-- /home/user/.virtualenvs/test3.7/bin/python3.7
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/user/projects/so, inifile:
collected 3 items                                                                                                   

so/test_api.py::test_fail FAILED                              [ 33%]
so/test_api.py::test_pass PASSED                              [ 66%]
so/test_api.py::test_fail_2 FAILED                            [100%]

============================== FAILURES ============================
______________________________ test_fail ___________________________

    def test_fail():
>       assert False
E       assert False

slotr_tracker/test_api.py:2: AssertionError
_____________________________ test_fail_2 _________________________

    def test_fail_2():
>       assert False
E       assert False

slotr_tracker/test_api.py:10: AssertionError
Some extra info: <Function 'test_fail'>
Some extra info: <Function 'test_fail_2'>
================ 2 failed, 1 passed in 0.03 seconds ===============
```

Here's a [pytest hooks reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#hooks) if you want to dig deeper into the subject.